# Windows batch if being selected on wrong value

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to use the CHOICE command in a little test batch file.
Here is the code I have:

```
@ECHO Off
choice /M "Is this correct"
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 echo This is correct
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 echo This is not correct
echo %errorlevel%
```

When I press `y` I get `This is correct` but when I press `n` I get `This is correct` and `This is not correct`

Why is the first option being triggered? From the `echo %errorlevel%` I can see the `errorlevel` is 2.

I am using `echo` here as an example, it the actual `batch` file I have a goto and I am getting the first goto triggered all the time.

Comment: `if ErrorLevel #` means *if `ErrorLevel` is **greater than or equal to** `#`*, so resort the conditions in descending order...

Comment: Alternately, capture the keypress literally using: `Echo Is this true?&For /F "Delims=" %%C in ('"%__AppDir__%\Choice.exe" /N /C:yn') Do Set "OPT=%%C"`

Comment: @aschipfl I've seen a few example where they use `if ErrorLevel N` which lead me to believe it was doing a ==, guess I was wrong. Thanks
@T3RR0R thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score -1):

Found on [ss64](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)

*IF ERRORLEVEL n statements should be read as IF Errorlevel >= number*

Meaning that it will execute all other functions that are less than or equal to ERRORLEVEL.

To avoid that, try this.

```
@Echo off
choice /m "Would you like to continue?"
if %ERRORLEVEL%==1 Echo Response was Y
if %ERRORLEVEL%==2 Echo Response was N
Echo %ERRORLEVEL%
pause
```

The %'s surrounding the ERRORLEVEL will display the value of the variable.